# Clipboard Manager: avoid password getting stored in history

Tags: password, clipboard, keepass, clipboard-manager

I use the clipboard manager diodon, but I think this problem is relevant to all clipboard managers on Ubuntu.

If I copy a password from keepass (the tool I use to manage my passwords), then the password gets stored in the history of the clipboard manager.

I would like to avoid this.

Is there a way to copy+paste a password from a password manager into the application, without getting stored in the clipboard manager?

I am willing to change my tools (diodon, keepass) if this feature is possible with other tools.

Comment: https://github.com/RedHatter/diodon-plugins seems to add deletion of history entries.

Comment: If you end up at this question from searching "parcellite" and "KeePassX", then know that these two managers do not appear to support such a security feature:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=770286

https://sourceforge.net/p/parcellite/feature-requests/62/

Answer (score 2):

`copyq` [has an option](https://superuser.com/questions/1112970/prevent-clipboard-manger-copyq-to-keep-data-from-keepass) to prevent storage of passwords copied from Keepass (or other apps).

With `diodon`, there should also be an option to exclude certain apps, presumably under `Ubuntu Settings > Security and privacy > Files and applications`

https://esite.ch/2013/12/storing-clipboard-items-infinitely-test-version/